# React Native Modal CallBack - Passing Props to Parent

Tags: react-native, callback, parent-child, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

I am using React Native Modal and am having difficulty passing back the props from the Modal to the class that called the Modal.

I have tried with the `onRequestClose()` and `onPress()` and setting a prop for callback data `googlePlacesPassedBackLocation`  but no success. I am trying to retrieve pastLocations from GooglePlaces. I can see in GooglePlaces that the location is being generated correctly. I am using the useState hook in both the Modal class and the GooglePlaces class.

I have read that this is a difficult thing to do as react doesn't really support it. Is it possible at all?

`import {StyleSheet, View, Modal, TouchableOpacity, Text, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';`

Parent Component:

```
const RegisterLocationScreen = ({navigation}) => {  
    var [pastLocations, setPastLocations] = useState([]);
    var [pastModalVisible, setModalPastVisible] = useState(false);

    const closeModal = (timeFrame) => {
        setModalPastVisible(false);
    };
    const openGooglePastModal = () => {
        setModalPastVisible(true)
    };

    return (
    <Modal visible={pastModalVisible} animationType={'slide'} onRequestClose={() => closeModal(pastLocations)}>
        <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
            <SafeAreaView style = {styles.safeAreaViewStyle} forceInset={{top: 'always'}}>
                 <GooglePlaces timePeriod="Past" googlePlacesPassedBackLocation={googlePlacesPassedBackLocation} />
                 <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonContainer} onPress={()=> closeModal('Past')}> 
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText} >
                            Close Modal
                        </Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>                        
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    </Modal>
    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonModal} onPress={() => openGooglePastModal()} >
            <Text style={styles.buttonModalText} >
                Past Locations 
            </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Child Component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

const API_KEY = '123omittedforsecurity';

const GooglePlaces = ({timePeriod}) => { 
    var [pastLocations, setPastLocations] = useState([]);

    const updateLocationArray = (data, details) =>{
        setPastLocations([
            ...pastLocations,
            details.geometry.location
          ]);        
    };

    return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder={timePeriod}
        onPress={(data, details) => { 
            updateLocationArray(data, details);
        }}
        ..../>
```

Comment: Can you show the parent component that shows it?

Comment: @Auticcat i added the parent and child components